# PHP Form Submission/Mailer - Microsoft Outlook Does Not See Image Attachment

Tags: php, image, forms, outlook, base64

I use the following PHP to email a form submission.  All email clients except for Microsoft Outlook see the submitted image attachment.  From what I've read, it appears Microsoft Outlook requires the use of \r\n or PHP_EOL somewhere in this code.  Or perhaps it requires a carriage return in the ob_start section.  If this is in fact the issue, I do not know where I am supposed to make a changes to this code.  When answering this question if you could please use this code to explain your answer - I would be greatly appreciative.  Thank you very much.

```
$strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

/* Set e-mail recipient */
$Receiver  = "someone@something.com";
$Subject = 'Form Name';

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$Name = check_input($_POST['Name'], "Please enter your name.");
$EmailAddress    = check_input($_POST['EmailAddress'], "Please enter your email address.");
$PhoneNumber = check_input($_POST['PhoneNumber'], "Please enter your phone number.");
$Age = check_input($_POST['Age'], "Please enter your age.");
$Comments = check_input($_POST['Comments'], "Please enter your comments.");
$Experience = check_input($_POST['Experience'], "Please enter your experience.");

/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $EmailAddress))
{
show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}

/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */

/* put priority here using Headers */
$Headers .= "From: someone@something.com\r\n";
$Headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$strSid."\"\r\n";

$filename = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
$filesize = filesize($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"]);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"])));

/* Picture Data and File Size is retrieved from tmp_name */

ob_start();

echo "
--PHP-mixed-$strSid
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-$strSid\"

--PHP-alt-$strSid
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Name: $Name
E-mail: $EmailAddress
Phone Number: $PhoneNumber
Age: $Age
Comments: $Comments
Experience: $Experience

--PHP-alt-$strSid

--PHP-mixed-$strSid
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=$filename
Content-Description: $filename
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename size=$filesize

$data
--PHP-mixed-$strSid--
";

/* Do not remove space before $data required */

$Message = ob_get_clean();

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($Receiver, $Subject, $Message, $Headers);
```

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Use PHPmailer or Swiftmailer. Both will reduce ALL of your mime-handling code to a single `->AddAttachment()` line.

Comment: For one thing, your first `$Headers` has a leading dot; remove it.

Comment: Hi Fred, I don't know where exactly in the code I need to remove it.  Can you use the code to illustrate your answer?

Comment: This line `$Headers .= "From: someone@something.com\r\n";` has a dot. Change it to `$Headers = "From: someone@something.com\r\n";` - Only subsequent uses of `$Headers` require a leading dot before the equal sign, not the first. It could be just that.

Comment: I tested your code with my suggestion above and received the file no problem, far as I could test without a form.

Comment: Issue still exists in Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Fred, thank you for pointing out the $Headers having the un-needed dot.  However, the issue still existed in Outlook.

I discovered the answer to the problem was to slightly modify the $Headers as follows:

```
$Headers = "From: someone@something.com\r\n";
$Headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$Headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-" . $strSid . "\"\r\n";
```

I also had to add two dashes to the second --PHP-alt-$strSid like so:

```
--PHP-alt-$strSid--
```

I also had to change Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename size=$filesize to:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename
```

Now Outlook and all other email clients are properly interpreting the email in its entirety using HTML and attachments.